# How to identify nonpubsub feeds using SyndicationFeed class in C#

Tags: c#, atom-feed, feed, websub, syndication

I have so many RSS and atom feed urls. I am using SyndicationFeed class for reading content of these feeds.
After viewing page source we can identify, because every feed with pubsubhub feature always have rel="hub" attribute.
eg. 
Suppose I have two feeds 
[Non pubsubhub feed]
http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533929/index.rss 
and
[pubsubhub feed]
http://allthingsd.com/feed/

Now my problem is to identify a pubsubhub feed using SyndicationFeed class. 
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C# person, but based on the docs, it looks like for each SyndicationFeed object, you can access its [links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.links.aspx). Then, for each of these [SyndicationLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationlink.aspx), you should check the `rel` element. It its value is `hub` then the `href` is the hub's url. If there is no `rel="hub"` element, then you can assume that the feed is not PubSubHubbub enabled :)

PS: Shameless plug: [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com/) acts as a default hub, which means you can subscribe to any feed whether they support PubSubHubbub or not and receive notifications for them (we also nomarlize the content!)